# Get upload file count

Tags: jquery, file, count, uploader

I am using jquery uploader from [here](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) and I would like to know how do I get the total number of files has been added and not uploaded.

There is no specific documentation on the new version so can anyone say me how do I do this?

As I need to get this way "`uploading 1 of n files`"

Here in the [documentation](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options) says:

```
$('#fileupload').bind('fileuploadadded', function (e, data) {
  //Here I need to get the upload count.
 });
```

And If I as shown below it gives me count as 1

```
var totalfiles = data.files.length; 
alert(totalfiles);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Following the documentation there's an event called 'fileuploadadd' that will fire every time a file has been added to the queue, so you could create a counter and increment it when the event is called.

```
var filestoupload =0;     
$('#fileupload').bind('fileuploadadd', function (e, data) {
      filestoupload++;
     });
```

Comment: @lgomezma-Thanks for that.I have done the same but I kept in the same loop inside so it has been taking 1 always.

Answer (score 2):

Get upload file count before upload.

```
  $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        ...
        change: function (e, data) {
            var idx=0;
            $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
                idx++;
            });
            alert(idx);
        }
        ...
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this way to count files uploaded and total file in fileupload jquery

```
var uploadedFileCount = 0;
var totalFileCount = 0;
$("#fileupload").fileupload({
   dataType: 'json',
   url: url,
   autoUpload: true,
   done: function (e, data) {
        //Some code
        uploadedFileCount = uploadedFileCount + 1;
      $("#UploadCount").html(uploadedFileCount + " of" + totalFileCount);
    }
  }).on('fileuploadadd', function (e, data) {
        totalFileCount = totalFileCount + 1;
    });
```